# Show that $p →(q ∨ r)$ and $(p ∧ ∼q) →r$ and $(p ∧ ∼r) →q$ are all logically equivalent.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, discrete-optimization

I need to show that the following are logical equivalent:

- $p → (q ∨ r) $
- $(p ∧ ∼q) →r$
- $(p ∧ ∼r) →q$

Here are the steps I took. I started with $p → (q ∨ r) $.

1. $p → (q ∨ r) $
2. $∼p ∨ (q ∨ r)$
3. $∼ (∼p ∨ (q ∨ r))$
4. $p ∧ ∼ (q ∨ r)$
5. $p ∧ (∼q) ∧ (∼r)$

My problem is how to justify going from $p ∧ (∼q) ∧ (∼r)$ to $(p ∧ ∼q) →r$ or $(p ∧ ∼r)$ →q.

Comment: Have you tried a truth table? They always work.

Comment: I have done truth tables, but I want to know how to prove using Logical Equivalence laws.

Comment: Try using $p \rightarrow q \equiv (\sim p ) \lor q$ and $\sim(\sim p)\equiv p$ and also associative property of $\lor$.

Comment: Step 3 is de Morgan's law.

Comment: I think I might have confused the negation with a conditional.

Comment: You might more explicitly display the logical equivalences among those 3 sentences. For example, your presentation doesn't explain whether you are merely deriving line 2 from line 1, and whether you are arguing that each pair among the 3 sentences is an equivalent pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done between step two and three is wrong. Obviously the 2nd $∼p ∨ (q ∨ r)$ is not equal to its complement the 3rd $∼ (∼p ∨ (q ∨ r))$

You could've continued as following to complete the proof:

3. $(∼p ∨ q ) ∨ r $ (associativity and commutativity)
4. $∼(∼p ∨ q ) \implies r$ (Conditional identity)
5. $ (p ∧ ∼ q ) \implies r$ (De Morgan's)

Notice that each step is connected with *if and only if* condition. So for the backward implication, you can reverse the order of the steps.

proving $ p  \implies (q ∨ r)$  if and only if $ (p ∧ ∼ r ) \implies q$ is almost same by writing  $(∼p ∨ r ) ∨ q $ on 3rd step onward.

Comment: Ok, I didn't catch that before. Thanks.

Comment: @monkeyplayz You're welcome.